# Does this result in a dangling pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

Does such a function result in a dangling pointer?

```
int *foo () {
    int a[2] = {2, 3};
    int *p = NULL;
    p = a;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Yes, because when `foo` exits, the memory holding `a` (on the stack) is de-allocated by virtue of stack management in the C calling sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You are returning a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration.  When the function returns the pointer is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Never return a pointer to an *automatic* local variable.
In your case variable `a` doesn't exist once `foo` returns, so the pointer to it will be invalid (invokes undefined behavior).

Comment: Technically, the returned pointer (p) will point to some memory location that's _probably_ still being used as the stack. However, there's no guarantee that something else hasn't overwritten that memory location by the time you get to looking at the returned pointer. Even if you don't get a segfault or other invalid pointer error, you can't count on it pointing to anything useful.